# About vector addition and absolute values in a subspace

Tags: absolute-value

So, given that $$W = \{[x, y] \mid y = |x| \} \in R_2$$ 
which one is correct, given that vector $v = [x_1,y_1]$ and $u = [x_2,y_2]$ 
are in $W$?
$$ 1.\ v+u = [x_1+x_2, \lVert x_1+x_2 \lVert\ ] $$
$$ 2.\ v+u = [x_1 , \lVert x_1 \lVert\ ] + [x_2 , \lVert x_2 \lVert\ ]
= [x_1+x_2, \lVert x_1\lVert + \lVert x_2 \lVert\ ] $$
I don't think they are equal, given that if $x_1 = -1$ and $x_2 = 1$, equation $1$ would give $[0, 0]$ while equation $2$ would give $[0, 2]$.

edit: $$W = \{[x, y] \mid y = |x| \} \in R_2$$

Comment: What do you mean by $y=|x|\in R_2$? Do you mean $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ (in which case $y=||x||\in\mathbb{R}$)? Or do you mean $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $R_2$?

Comment: And in case $R_2$ is indeed supposed to be $\mathbb R$ and $\lVert\ldots\rVert$ to be $|\ldots|$, one has $[x_1,y_1] + [x_2,y_2] = [x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2]$, and then substitutes $y_i = |x_i|$ and gets (2), not (1).

Comment: Please see edit. Thanks @arseniiv